# d3js calculation not working in Safari in Mac OS Big Sur

Tags: javascript, macos, d3.js, safari

I am using d3js v6 on Mac OS Big Sur. Cases is loaded from a csv file. In Safari a calculation does not work. d.rate is correct in Safari, Chrome and Firefox browsers but in Safari Cases isn't.

> ```
>       cases.forEach(function(d) {    
>        PHUpopulation.forEach (function(e) {
>          if (e.Reporting_PHU == d.key) {
>              d.rate = d.count/e.Population*100000;  
> // console.log ("d.rate calculate ", d.rate) // OK in safari
> // console.log ("cases after calculate rate ", cases) // not OK in Safari
>              } // end if
>        }) // end PHUpopulation.forEach 
>      }) // end cases.forEach
>  }) // end phuPopulationCSV
> ```

Console output in Safari

> ```
> cases after calculate rate 
> Array (34)
> 0 Array (2)
> 0 "Toronto Public Health"
> 1 5598
> Array Prototype
> ```

> ```
> Console output in Chrome
> cases after calculate rate  (34) [Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2)]
> 0: Array(2)
> 0: "Toronto Public Health"
> 1: 5598
> count: 5598
> key: "Toronto Public Health"
> rate: 204.93701243716527
> length: 2
> __proto__: Array(0)
> ```

Any ideas why?

Comment: I realized that this problem occurs in a couple of maps that use D3js V6. They were adapted from V3. A V3 version works correctly in Safari.

Comment: This problem seems only after the page is refreshed a couple of times. If I restart Safari it works again for a couple of times. The V3 page works all the time.

Comment: I reverted to a d3js v3 version of the map. If anyone can suggest how to fix the V6 version I will be happy to know it.